# @font-face fails to load on some requests, due to javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Having a weird issue,

I am testing webfonts

here is my css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(/assets/opensans.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I am using the font throughout my application and have no issue expect on one page.
I have a fair amount of JS on this page, the JS is positioning the elements and setting the height of the right div.

On some requests the webfont is not loading (at all)

e.g.
[image]

I can reproduce this on chrome on windows 7. But only sometimes.

Those box's should be full of text, the text you can see is where I am not using the @font-face.

I have javascript events tied to the window resize that change the width height of the right div. Interestingly when I resize the window the font seems to load.

I cannot see any errors in the console or in network tab on chrome.

Bit lost on what it could be.

Comment: Which order are you CSS files in? (assuming you have multiple files)

Comment: Have you considered using a backup font so at least the text is visible, eg `.something { font-face: "Open Sans", sans-serif; }`?

Comment: Also when you say you dont see any errors in the network tab, are you checking if `/assets/opensans.woff` returns a 200 when the font doesnt render?

Comment: Adding on to @stackErr's [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469755/font-face-fails-to-load-on-some-requests-due-to-javascript#comment34272530_22469755), make sure you load all CSS **before** any JavaScript

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle link if it's feasible?

Comment: I get this in chrome too, especially when developing, reloading frequently sometimes results in fonts being blank after the page has rendered. I'm thinking it probably only happens if you hit reload a lot. Hoping, anyway.

Comment: Did you try loading your page in Incognito Mode? Did you still notice the issue?

Comment: I do not recommend using WOFF, it offers nothing better than TTF but unneeded protection, and it is actually weights more. useless format, i have no idea why many use it. they probably don't even know what it is meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476) with Chrome. It has been fixed, so wait for an update?

Or you can force re-painting via CSS (taken from the bug report) which should display the font:

```
body
{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix{
    from{   opacity: 1; }
    to{ opacity: 1; }
}
```

or JS:

```
var body = document.getElementByTag("body")[0];
var disp = body.style.display;
body.style.display = 'none';
body.style.display = disp;
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
url(/assets/opensans.woff)
```

can be well

```
url(assets/opensans.woff)
```

example use:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

body {
       font-family: 'MyFontFamily', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

*if you use jquery not use multiple versions*

Comment: I doubt it's a path issue otherwise OP would see errors in their *Net* console

Comment: assuming that it can be

Comment: add please code in [github](https://github.com), [jsfidlee](http://jsfiddle.net), or other site.